# не могу указать путь PHP

Tags: php

Все файлы находятся в одной папке, но через include не могу перейти по ней. Глобальный путь так же не помог. Искал проблему в интернете, но, видимо, плохо искал. На это форуме подобные вопросы спрашивают про "обычные" хосты, я использую локальный хост.

```
<html>
<?php include_once "header.php" ?>
<?php include_once "leftblock.php" ?>

<div class="content">
content
</div>

<?php include_once "footer.php" ?>
</html>
```

Comment: где пример кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что проверил - работает и без указания пути. Вы как тестируете этот код? У вас запущен сервер Apache или Nginx, и вы пишете что то вроде "localhost" в адресной строке?

Если да - странно, должно работать, проверяйте PHP. Как проверить? Напишите в этом же файле в любом месте

```
<?php echo 'PHP работает!'; ?>
```

Если эта надпись выведется на экран, значит PHP работает, и нужно искать проблему в подключаемых файлах. Может там код написан вне

```
<?php ?>
```

Либо **может быть файл имеет расширение отличное от .php**? Или вы пытаетесь протестировать файл, просто открывая его двумя кликами мышью? В первом случае меняем расширение на .php, во втором имейте в виду - PHP код не будет работать без PHP сервера.

Поиграл в угадайку как мог. Надеюсь один из выстрелов попал в цель... В следующий раз прикрепляйте код и названия файлов, максимум информации о вопросе.

Удачи